# Expectation question in probability

Tags: probability

Hi I have been working on this question and I managed to get the answer using the hint, but I do not quite understand the reasoning behind the hint. Could someone explain?

You are sequentially placing m items among m cells according to the
following probability distribution: each item will be independently put in cell
j with probability $P_j$ , j = 1, 2, . . . , m. Let X denote the number of collisions
that occur, where a collision occurs whenever an item is put into a non-empty
cell.
Show that the expected number of collisions that occur is equal to

$E[X] = \sum_{j = 1}^m(1-p_j)^m$

[HINT: Let $X_i$ = 1 if a collision occurs when the ith item is placed, and $X_i = 0$
otherwise. Determine $E [X_i]$ by making use of $E[X_i] = \sum_j \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1|\text{placed in cell j}) * p_j$ and observe that, conditional on item i being placed in cell j, item i will cause
a collision if any of the preceding i − 1 items were put in cell j.]

My question is this, why do we consider the probability of item i causing a collision if the preceding i-1 items are put in the same cell. Why not consider all the remaining m - 1 items too? I understand that this will cause a double counting, but isn't that easily remedied by dividing by 2?

Comment: I don't think dividing by $2$ will work. What if $3$ items go in the same cell. Your method will count it $3$ times and then divide by $2$. But the result should be $2$ collisions, not $3/2$.